# how to phrase a conditional condition?

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, self-join

I want to query a self join that will only join on the first condition and only if it cant find a match it will join the second condition

I tried this syntax which doesnt work for me, because it will understandbly always join both conditions

```
SELECT a.id, a.id2, a.col1, b.id2 from test a
LEFT JOIN test b ON a.id = b.id AND 
(SUBSTRING(a.col1, 1, LEN(a.col1) - 2) = b.col1 OR b.col1 = '00')
```

**What I need is like an XOR instead.**

Example:
table

| id | id2 | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4080 | 2147 | 00 |
| 4080 | 2148 | 0001 |
| 4080 | 2149 | 0002 |
| 4080 | 2150 | 000201 |
| 3820 | 2069 | 00 |
| 3820 | 2070 | 000101 |

desired result

| a.id | a.id2 | a.col1 | b.id2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4080 | 2147 | 00 | NULL |
| 4080 | 2148 | 0001 | 2147 |
| 4080 | 2149 | 0002 | 2147 |
| 4080 | 2150 | 000201 | 2149 |
| 3820 | 2069 | 00 | NULL |
| 3820 | 2070 | 000101 | 2069 |

Data

```
CREATE TABLE [test](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[id2] [int] NOT NULL,
[col1] [varchar](6) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO [test] VALUES
(4080,2147,'00'),
(4080,2148,'0001'),
(4080,2149,'0002'),
(4080,2150,'000201'),
(3820,2069,'00'),
(3820,2070,'000101')
```

Comment: You'll have to write the XOR condition as a combination of `AND ... OR`. SQL Server has no XOR operator. It's also better to put that in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: As for `SUBSTRING(a.col1, 1, LEN(a.col1) - 2)` that's a problem. Indexes only accelerate exact or range searches, not substring searches. This function call will force the server to scan the entire table for matches. What is `col1`? Does it represent a hierarchy? In that case `hierarchyId` is the correct type, which *does* support indexing and parent/child searches.

Comment: Maybe you can use a CTE (common table expression)? Sounds like a good fit for this kind of problem.

Comment: I cannot change the typing, you mean by putting the SUBSTRING in WHERE Clause this query performs better? Performance isnt really my issue, I need it just to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two separate left joins and then pick the "best match" as needed.

For example:

```
select a.*, 
  case when a.col1 = '00' then null else coalesce(b.id2, c.id2) end as bid2
from test a
left join test b on b.id = a.id 
  and SUBSTRING(a.col1, 1, LEN(a.col1) - 2) = b.col1
left join test c on c.id = a.id and c.col1 = '00'
```

Result:

```
 id    id2   col1    bid2 
 ----- ----- ------- ---- 
 4080  2147  00      null 
 4080  2148  0001    2147 
 4080  2149  0002    2147 
 4080  2150  000201  2149 
 3820  2069  00      null 
 3820  2070  000101  2069
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bwM7v_sK).